# Can't tap an annotation callout if it overlaps with another annotation?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am displaying a set of annotations on an `MKMapView`, using a custom `MKMarkerAnnotationView` with `displayPriority = .required` so that there is no clustering or hiding, and a `UIButton` as its `rightCalloutAccessoryView`.

When I tap an annotation on the map, the callout displays as expected, but when I tap the callout or its accessory, if the tap overlaps with another marker on the map, the tap doesn't register.

Below is a Playground-friendly example of the problem. Notice how the callout doesn't respond to taps when it overlaps with another annotation on the map.

```
import MapKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
                 calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        print("Callout tapped!")
    }
}

class CustomAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            canShowCallout = true
            rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            titleVisibility = .hidden
            subtitleVisibility = .hidden
            displayPriority = .required
        }
    }
}

let mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:800, height:800))
let controller = MapViewController()
mapView.delegate = controller

mapView.register(CustomAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

let coordinate1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.334922, -122.009033)
let annotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation1.coordinate = coordinate1
annotation1.title = "Annotation 1"
annotation1.subtitle = "Subtitle 1"

let coordinate2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.335821492347556, -122.0071341097355)
let annotation2 = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation2.coordinate = coordinate2
annotation2.title = "Annotation 2"
annotation2.subtitle = "Subtitle 2"

mapView.addAnnotation(annotation1)
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation2)

var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
let mapRegionSpan = 0.02
mapRegion.center = coordinate1
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = mapRegionSpan
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = mapRegionSpan
mapView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)

let mapViewController = MapViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = mapView
```

And an image to illustrate the problem.

[image: Overlapping annotations]

Any help on this would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teammate was able to solve this issue. The idea is to disable user interaction for all other annotations on the map when an annotation is selected, and then re-enable it when the annotation is deselected.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    for nearbyAnnotation in mapView.annotations {
        let annotationView = mapView.view(for: nearbyAnnotation)
        if annotationView != nil {
            annotationView!.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect _: MKAnnotationView) {
    for nearbyAnnotation in mapView.annotations {
        let annotationView = mapView.view(for: nearbyAnnotation)
        if annotationView != nil {
            annotationView!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```